# Reports based on multiple tables MSAccess

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I designed a report(salary slip) with many controls(text boxes) in MSAccess 2016.
There are 2 tables Employee details and salary details.
Some controls that need data from employee details table and some from salary table.
I have 2 primary keys

- Sl.No
- Employee id

for both the tables.
and I have connected the employee id through relationship.
How to specify the expression in the text boxes so that i get the record that matches both the table?

Comment: What we need to know are the foreign keys used to link the tables.

Comment: employee id is the foreign key. I have connected the employee id from both the tables using relationsip feature.

Answer (score 1):

Use a query as record source of your report instead of a table. Then you don't need any expressions in the textboxes, just the column names. I usually give the query the same name as the report but with another prefix. E.g. for report `rptSalary` the query is named `qrptSalary`.

```
SELECT * FROM
    Employee E
    LEFT JOIN SalaryDetails S
        ON E.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID
```

In the report, you can insert group headers and footers. You would use `EmployeeID` as grouping column. Then you can place the employee fields in the employee group header, the salary details in the details section and any sums in the group footer.

Comment: No, but the employee fields will be multiplied by the number of salary detail entries. If you want to print the same employee name repeatedly per salary detail record, you don’t need any grouping.